# How to fix "Whitelabel Error Page" on spring framework - GET request is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, get, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to make a "Hello World" controller with spring boot and the GET request is not working. What can i do to fix this?

I used spring initializer at https://start.spring.io/ and in the Dependencies I chose web

I've tried to use diffrent annotations like @GetMapping

```
package com.example.hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I want the output to be "Hello World" but the actual output is "Whitelabel Error Page"

Comment: are you sure you call `http://localhost:8080/a` ? it work fine with me

Comment: How does the project structure look like?

Comment: You can also try the starter project which is a perfect working example and maps 100% on what you need. It has even an embedded tomcat so you just run the main class and you can access your controller in the browser.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: @YCF_L Hi. yes I used http://localhost:8080/a

Comment: @EugenCovaci i used the spring initializer and added a package and the controller in the java folder

Comment: @IoanM i used the spring initializer

Comment: Tell me the qualified name of the controller and the qualified name of the main class.

Comment: @EugenCovaci the name of the controller class is HelloController and the name of the main class is DemoApplication

Comment: @EugenCovaci I added the main class code and the whole controller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is related to your project structure, by default Spring Boot will scan the components below your main application class.

In your case your main is located at `package com.example.demo;`, and your controller is located at `package com.example.hello;`.

I would recommend you to keep your controller in a new package below the `com.example.demo` package, like `com.example.demo.controller` as per structure mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html).

If you really want to use the `com.example.hello` package, you may need to add the `@ComponentScan("com.example.hello")`, which becomes hard to mantain in the future.

More info can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues.
I suggest you start with everything under the same package (move initilizer to com.example.hello for instance), it is most likely related to the project structure.

Here is an article about the issue:

https://www.dev2qa.com/spring-boot-resolve-whitelabel-error-page-example/

Quote from link above:

> So if you use @SpringBootApplication annotation in your spring boot
>   main class, you must place the main class in root package as bellow to
>   avoid whitelabel error page.

Comment: Agreed.  I just had this error and it was just a copy paste-ism, the Controller class was missing a package definition at the top.

Answer (score 0):

In my case having the RequestMapping method helloWorld inside the DemoApplication Class wouldn't work.
When I split the methods by creating the HelloController Class and adding the helloWorld method to this Class, I got the page returning "Hello World".